# How to horizontal scrolling list with minimum rows using tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to do a list **with 3 rows** and **with horizontal scroll**, like this one:

[image: clubhouse interests list]

But currently I only got this result using tailwindcss, with this huge "gap" between the items, that's because I'm using grid to achieve this result:

[image: my current horizontal list]

```
  <ul class="grid overflow-x-auto grid-rows-3 grid-flow-col gap-2 mt-2 grid-cols-max">
    <li
      v-for="interest in interests"
      :key="interest.id"
      class="py-1 px-2 w-min text-sm whitespace-nowrap bg-white rounded-lg border border-blueGray-200"
    >
      {{ interest.symbol }} {{ interest.title }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

How can I remove this horizontal space between the items? The behavior of everything else is ok.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way is using `flex` instead of `grid`

Comment: Ok Parco, using flex the space between items will be good, but how could I set 3 rows of content?

Comment: It will adapt to the `width` of your container and if you use `flex-wrap: wrap;` it will wrap itself into the necessary rows

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
grid-rows-[masonry]
```

or

```
grid-cols-[masonry]
```

Source: [Tailwind Connect 2023 — Keynote](https://youtu.be/CLkxRnRQtDE?t=2046)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34680810)